RegEx to find string representing local paths
I'm trying to find all strings which are local paths like:
@/path/to
@@/path/to
./path/to
../path/to
../../path/to

And at the same time ignore all string, which could be a module like
@next/module

Therefore I use this regexp:
^[.\/|~\/|@\/|@@\/]

But this also matches the module, which I don't want to. I thought I have to search for a starting DOT or AT followed by a SLASH should work...
RegEx

That regex is not what you want.  You are using square brackets, which creates a character a class: it matches any ONE CHARACTER that is within the brackets.  I suspect you wanted parentheses.

You might use:
^(?:@@?|\.\.?)\/\S+

The pattern matches:

^ Start of string
(?:@@?|\.\.?) Match either @ @@ . ..
\/\S+ Match / followed by 1+ non whitspace characters

Regex demo
Or allowing 1 or 2 @ chars at the start or optional repetitions of 1 or 2 dots followed by / and matching only word characters:
^(?:@@?\/|(?:\.\.?\/)+)\w+(?:\/\w+)*

Regex demo
